# Rails migration generator not generating columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Low sleep so probably missing something trivial, but...

Based on various doc readings, I thought that this would generate a migration with table and column declarations included...

```
$ script/generate migration Question ordinal_label:string question_text:string
```

However, the result is...

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

Why is there no table or columns?

Comment: In case one day they implement the feature of taking into account the fields definitions in constructional migrations (as many of us hope), you'd notice that your migration's name is confusing. Infact it becomes the name of the *migration class* and you'll end up with two classes with the same name. I don't know if it could be a problem, but it might well be so. To obtain the same name as model generator does, use: g migration create_questions(...).That is:1) prepend a "create_" and 2)use plural.Trick: remember that mig.name is a class name.Feel free to update your question and drop my comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `script/generate migration` command does not create columns on new tables.

Only if you wish add, for instance, a column to an existing table you can pass the new column as an argument:

```
script/generate migration add_text_to_question question_text:string
```

For what you are trying to achieve you have to create a new model:

```
script/generate model Question ordinal_label:string question_text:string
```

This will generate a migration like the following:

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      create_table :questions do |t|
        t.string  :ordinal_label
        t.string  :question_text
        t.timestamps
      end
    end

    def self.down
      drop_table :questions
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is of course the solution, but my complain is that it comes from experience while it might be easily documented. Or it might give an error when user enters columns definitions while not adding/removing, instead of simply ignoring them. The confusion arises from the fact that the help for rails g migration presents it as a way to create migration in general, not just migration that add or remove columns. Reading the help you realize that this task (adding/removing) is just one of the options available. So nothing lets you guess that columns are not considered in constructional migrations.

Answer (score 3):

That should be

```
$ script/generate model Question ordinal_label:string question_text:string
```

You will also end up with a model, unit test and fixture of course. `script/generate` with `migrate` will add a column to an existing table but not to a new one.

```
$ script/generate migration add_question_text_to_question question_text:string
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a verb if you are modifying a model.

```
script/generate migration AddLabelToQuestion label:string
```

or to generate a new model, you use your statement above, but substitute migration for model.